# Linq to Sql .Except not working if null in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a simple query.

It checks for a list of rooms - `prebookedRooms`

It then checks for another list of rooms, but uses the `.Except` operator, to remove any `prebookedRooms` from the subsequent list:

```
        // Get list of rooms already booked
        var prebookedRooms = dbt.Rooms
            .Where(room => room.Rentals.Any(rental =>
                (dteFrom >= rental.check_in && dteFrom < rental.check_out)));

        // Get list of rooms
        var rooms = dbt.Rooms.Where(r => r.h_id == AccID)
            .Except(prebookedRooms)
            .GroupBy(p => p.RoomTypes).Select(g => new RatesViewModel
            {
                TypeName = g.Key.t_name,
                TypeID = g.Key.t_id,
                TypeCount = g.Count()
            })
            .ToList();
```

This works fine - with `rooms` returning a list of rooms, with `prebookedRooms` excluded.

However, if `prebookedRooms` doesn't return any records (ie. Empty "Enumeration yielded no results") - then I get an error when executing the second query (var rooms = ...):

`The cast to value type 'Int64' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`

Is there anyway of checking if prebookedRooms is empty, within the second query, so I can avoid this error?

**prebookedRooms model:**

```
public class Room
{
    [Key]
    public long room_id { get; set; }
    public long hotel_id { get; set; }
    public long type_id { get; set; }
}
```

The error as it appears in VS is:
[image]

Thank you,

Mark

Comment: Is there any reason you can't split the query and test if the result of `dbt.Rooms.Where(r => r.h_id == AccID).Except(prebookedRooms)` isn't null before trying the `.GroupBy`?

Comment: Hi - rooms will always return records - it's only when prebookedRooms has no records, that the rooms query fails.  Thanks, Mark

Comment: That's my point - by splitting the query at the `Except` you can check it's not null before doing the `GroupBy`.

Comment: How do I split the query though?  I'm not sure how to do it, and then continue with the GroupBy afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just resign from `Except` and write:

```
    var rooms = dbt.Rooms.Where(r => r.h_id == AccID)
        .Where(room => !room.Rentals.Any(rental =>
            (dteFrom >= rental.check_in && dteFrom < rental.check_out))).
        .GroupBy(p => p.RoomTypes).Select(g => new RatesViewModel
        {
            TypeName = g.Key.t_name,
            TypeID = g.Key.t_id,
            TypeCount = g.Count()
        })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [null coalescing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator: `??` and then getting the `IQueryable<T>` equivalent of `Enumerable<T>.Empty`, which is `Enumerable<T>.Empty().AsQueryable()` and `DefaultIfEmpty` with an invalid room, so it doesn't go crazy about it being null || empty:

```
    var rooms = dbt.Rooms.Where(r => r.h_id == AccID)
        .Except(prebookedRooms ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>().AsQueryable().DefualtIfEmpty(new Room() { room_id = -1, hotel_id = -1, type_id = -1}))
        .GroupBy(p => p.RoomTypes).Select(g => new RatesViewModel
        {
            TypeName = g.Key.t_name,
            TypeID = g.Key.t_id,
            TypeCount = g.Count()
        })
        .ToList();
```

I don't know your type, so I don't know what to put in the `Enumerable.Empty<T>` call's generic parameter. Add that yourself.

Also, remember to be `using System.Linq`!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately it had no effect (I did add the correct type - but prebookedRooms still "yielded no results" and when the second query was run, the error remained.

Comment: That's pretty weird... means it treats empty collections as `null`.

Comment: I tried adding the ?? in the second query, as per your update above - but still I get the same error.

Comment: @fixit Is there one value that will never be in the DB and you could therefore safely pass it to DefaultIfEmpty, so then it won't throw that weird error?

Comment: Hi - I've been checking that out - preBookedRooms would hold a collection of `long, long, long` - eg. 1245,56,3 - how would I enter that into DefaultIfEmpty() - DefaultIfEmpty(1245,56,3) isn't allowed.  Thank you again.

Comment: So could you post me the actual type of preBookedRooms? Is it an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<long>>`? `IEnumerable<IList<long>>`? `IEnumerable<long[]>`? `IEnumerable<List<long>>`?

Comment: Hi - I've added the model that prebookedRooms is in the question above - thank you.

Comment: @fixit Fixed on the post above. :)

Comment: Thanks - I think I understand what you're trying to do - but I'm getting the Error proj.Models.Room' does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments - thank you, Mark

Comment: I changed to: .Except(prebookedRooms ?? Enumerable.Empty<Room>().AsQueryable().DefaultIfEmpty(new Room{room_id=0,hotel_id=0, type_id=0})) - but the error still appears (As per original post) - thanks again.

Comment: The original post issue? Do you mind posting the exception details (wrap it in a try + catch, console.writeline the exception) please?

Comment: Yes of course - I've posted a full screenshot if that helps?  Thanks again, Mark